# Laravel - Status Code: 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs2, controller

hello i want to update my  data in DB using V-form but 500 internal server error show:
this is my function in  controller:

```
   public function update(Request $request, $id)
{   $data =$request->all();

    //
    $client = Client::where('id', $data['client_id'])->first();

    DB::table('projets')->where('id',$id)->update(['name'=>$data['name'],'durre'=>$data['durre'],'description'=>$data['description'],'owner'=>$client->name,'budget'=>$data['budget']]);


}
```

and this is my route:

```
Route::apiResource('projet' ,'API\ProjetController');
```

and this is the vue code:

```
  modifier(){

           this.form.put('api/projet/'+ this.form.id).then(function(){

         $('#AjouterProjet').modal('hide')

                seww.fire(
                'Modifier!',
                'Your User has been Updated.',
                'success'
                )
                fire.$emit('ajoutprojet');

         }).catch(function(){

         })
        },
```

Comment: Check the last file on `storage/logs` directory and post the full error message, please.

Comment: the are many lines  in laravel.log
which lines concerned the error and thanks ?

Comment: try to find the last error on this file, errors are in this format: [[date]] [error_message] [stacktrace]

Comment: i resolve it thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

When you get 500 error, Check the last file on `storage/logs` directory and try to find the last error on this file, errors are in this format:

```
[date_time] [error_message] [stacktrace]
```

Answer (score 0):

In your route specify the Controller function to execute like this

```
Route::apiResource('projet' ,'API\ProjetController@update');
```